# How to calculate the topological distance using ArcMap or other softwares?

Tags: geolocation, geometry, gis, postgis

I'd like to calculate the topological distance instead of Euclidean distance between two polygons. The distance between two neighboring polygons is 1, between two polygons connecting through a common neighbor is 2 and so on.

Is there any easy method to calculate the topological distance? I searched this question but found no solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have adjacency information stored in the attributes of your polygons, or do you have to derive that from the geometry? In the latter case, can you rely on adjacent polygons having a vertex in common, with *exactly* the same coordinates, or do you have to take rounding into consideration as well? Do you need the combinatoric distance between all pairs of polygons, or only with relation to a few selected ones? The GIS SE might help, http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/10942 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/43275 in particular.

Comment: @MvG  Thanks. You can check whether my solution is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to implement this calculation using existing software.

First, import the shp file to PostgreSQL using the PostGIS plugin.

Second, use the ST_Touches function to calculate each polygon's neighboring polygons.

Third, take each polygon as a point, and construct a new network.

Finally, calculate the shortest path between each two points using the Dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: Simple [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) instead of Dijkstra should be sufficient. Otherwise this looks sound, although one should check whether `ST_Touches` does the right thing for the given data.

Comment: also refer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62525/st-touches-for-more-than-just-one-geometry

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to search the distance between Polygon A & B

Here are the steps that I will took:

Distance = 1;

1. Check whether Polygon B is the neighbor of Polygon A, If it is=Finish, If not go to point 2.
2. Calculate the coordinate centroid (the middle point) of all neighbouring Polygons, and Polygon B
3. Count the distance between the neighbouring centroid to Polygon B centroid, select the polygon with the closest distance (Polygon C)
4. Distance = Distance + 1, Check whether Polygon B is the neighbor of Polygon C, If it is=Finish, If not, Polygon A = Polygon C, go to Point 2

At the end you'll get the distance.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's a practical algorithm. But I want to use the existing software to obtain the result. And now I find a way to implement this calculation.